# Reclaim HDD from LVM

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I installed CentOS 7. It decided to give me almost no options during the install process, and proceeded to use up nearly the whole disk for a LVM block (it wouldn't let me leave space empty).

The problem is that I knew I wanted to install Windows along side this at a later time on another partition.

However, the stupid LVM block is taking up the entire drive - even when I remove the stupid partition from LVM.

My GUID SSD looks like this:

- 210MB - Some FAT filesystem
- 1.1GB - Some XFS filesystem
- 499GB - LVM2 PV

I had a 200GB volume in that LVM block which was to be devoted to Windows, which I just deleted... But naturally LVM isn't giving up that space.

How do I make that stupid LVM block smaller so I can put another partition on the top-level disk partition itself (i.e. have the GPT know that there's another partition there)?

EDIT: More information from commands I didn't know existed:

```
[root@localhost]/home/chris# pvdisplay -m
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p3
  VG Name               cl
  PV Size               464.57 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              118928
  Free PE               38144
  Allocated PE          80784
  PV UUID               CdXGC7-4tTX-BWRD-gOMX-dZcz-bEE2-W11sPy

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 12799:
    Logical volume  /dev/cl/root
    Logical extents 0 to 12799
  Physical extent 12800 to 76799:
    Logical volume  /dev/cl/home
    Logical extents 0 to 63999
  Physical extent 76800 to 80783:
    Logical volume  /dev/cl/swap
    Logical extents 0 to 3983
  Physical extent 80784 to 118927:
    FREE
```

It seems pvresize is the right answer. Its man page says that it will refuse to resize if the new size is too small, so it seems safe... Is this the right command? If so, how do know exactly how to big to change the partition to later? Is `gparted` the right tool for that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you want to do is to remove the PV from its volume group, making the disk space it had used available for other uses.

There are a few "**if**s" here

- If you have a LV in this PV, you need to remove it (obviously backing up your data before if you need the data). You can recreate it on another PV later.
- If this is the only PV in your VG, you want to remove the whole VG, this is done by `vgremove vgname`
- If there other PVs in that VG, that you want to keep, use `vgreduce vgname pvpath`

Finally use `pvremove pvpath` to remove the orphaned PV (with pvpath most likely being `/dev/sda2`, you should check with `pvdisplay` first)

I recommend you use `wipefs -a pvpath` on your PV after releasing it, but make sure you use the correct pvpath (check with `pvdisplay` before releasing it)

After that, you can use the partitioning tool of your choice to adapt the partitions to your liking, this might include creating a smaller PV or not.

Comment: There's no way to *resize* the PV? I have to *delete* it then *re-create* it?

Comment: You can use `pvresize` to change the size of the PV, then change the partition table accordingly. This needs great care, though - I recommend you backup anyway.

Comment: First use `pvdisplay -m` to show the mapped part of the PV (i.e. which parts are assigned to LVs), this gives you the info for `pvresize`. If you need to resize an LV, remember you first need to shrink the FS, only then can you safely shrink the LV

Comment: It seems that is going down the right path. I just used `pvresize` [successfully, I hope] and now `pvdisplay -m` no longer shows the extremely large free space at the end. How do I know exactly what size to resize the partition to? I don't want to get burned with MB vs MiB accounting differences or blocks or reserved size or anything. Also, please add this (along with your comments above) to your answer so I can mark it as the right answer.

Comment: `pvdisplay` takes a `--units` parameter, that allows you to display in any unit you want (decimal or binary). The unit `b` is bytes, so you get the best granularity.

Comment: I recommend you make the partition a bit bigger than necessary to be on the safe side, then use `pvresize /dev/something` (without a size given) to fill the partition. YOu can then use `lvresize +100%FREE /dev/mapper/something` to resize an LV.

Comment: I used `pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize $(( 80784 * 4 + 1 )) /dev/nvme0p1' and it accepted that (it balked without the `+1`). Then restarted to use `gparted` boot disk to resize the actual partition. However, `gparted` didn't boot so I restarted but then CentOS 7 went into "Welcome to Emergency Mode!" The drive was operable to recover data, but something seriously messed up CentOS. Bottom line: the installer defaulting to use LVM and filling the whole volume was the straw that broke the camel's back and now I'm no longer a Linux user; I don't need that kind of crap in my life.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. The outcome notwithstanding, I could not figure out what the appropriate steps *were* until you pointed me in the right direction. The fact that it went haywire just means that a complicated, dangerous, low-level tool was complicated, dangerous, and low-level.

Comment: You told the system to resize the PV to only  80784 * 4 + 1 **bytes**, while it contained 80784 * 4 **Megabytes** of data, which is obviously a bad idea.  the mentioned `--units` parameter (or a calculation in bytes) would have avoided that. It's a pity you went back to the old world, but maybe Windows is a better match for you. Be advised though: Windows Pro defaults to using the whole disk in its own LVM format!

Comment: It apparently assumed MiB. If I didn't have the `+1`, it said it couldn't do it because that size was too small; with the `+1`, it did. `pvdisplay` then showed the same output as above, just without the additional `FREE` space at the end and with the PV Size reading the correct value.